# Is there any way (property etc) in maven to know the current target goal (not the current running goal, but the specified one on the shell: mvn goal)?

Tags: maven

I would like to set the maven.skip.tests property only if maven is invoked with a certain goal.
I am thinking on using the build-helper-maven-plugin:regex-properties, but I need to know if my goal is present in the maven invocation itself.

It would be nice if we could set global maven properties on my particular plugin default-cli execution's config, but that does not seem feasible.

Comment: First what goal are we talking about and more why ? Apart from that `mvn xx` is not a goal it's a life cycle... a goal is called via `mvn plugin:goal`... which usually makes not really sense...

Comment: Your questions looks more like you want a maven profile that both runs the goal and sets other properties.

Comment: But a phase is comprised of goals, I mean if you execute mvn compile, that is effectively like telling execute all lifecycle up to compile:compile, or whatever is your last binded goal (or default)